# Background image autoresizing in half page

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to replicate a design like the one at [this page](http://www.fratellipollastrelli.it/azienda/), so basically split a page in two, on one half a div with an image as background that fills all this half, on the second half some text.

I tried using the css i can see with my browser, mixing it with bootsrap. All this into a Drupal view, but this is quite an irrilevant information.
What i did is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="height: auto;" >
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-image: url('[field_image]');background-attachment: fixed; background-position: 0% 50%;  background-repeat: no-repeat;width: 50%; height: 100%; background-size: 50% auto"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 txt" ><p>[body]</p> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But it does not behave like the page i'm referring to. 
I think it is somehow linked to the height:100% of row class.

Another question is: how can i make the page to focus only on a section if i scroll in the middle of two images like it does on that page?

Regards.

Comment: If you view the source, it looks like for each "row" they are using the `<div>`'s `rel` attribute to divide content into sections, and by using the inline styling for a constant height, they just divide each section's height into `750px`, and use some JavaScript to manipulate the scroll event/focus the content. I know this doesn't answer but perhaps it could help you. They probably use the current scroll position and compare it to the `rel` attribute or something, and calculate the difference in height and scroll using that.

Comment: @MarkC. Thanks Mark, any help is very appreciated. I saw that rel, but i saw also that it's put inline after the first scroll, so i suspect it's some jQuery script somewhere that can do the trick automatically.
And the inline height of the section resize as the window does, if you try to view the page flexibily, you can see the height of the rows change too.

Comment: Check [this](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) library out. I wonder if you can get up and running with it.

Comment: @MarkC.Thanks a lot! I really needed that, even if for another project.

Comment: Search javascript parralex scrolling.